# Принцип работы контроллера

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Добрый день, так как только начал изучать Spring и даже по аналогии сделал первое web-приложение, но все равно есть вопросы, и описание в инете тяжело дается понятию. А именно когда контроллер создаем. (паттерн MVC).

вот есть контроллер

```
@Controller
public class ContactController {

@Autowired
private ContactService contactService;

@RequestMapping("/index")
public String listContacts(Map<String, Object> map) {

    map.put("contact", new Contact());
    map.put("contactList", contactService.listContact());

    return "contact";
}
```

Но мне никак непонятно, что в методе происходит, мы в него передает мапу, заполняем мапу, и далее возвращаем ключ мапы. Я понял, что ключ мапы которые возвращаем, он как раз совпадает с файлом jsp, в котором все выводим.

Но где мы в метод передаем мапу? Где этот метод вызывается?

Когда я убрал этот параметр и удалил заполнение мапы, то у меня пустой естественно вывелся список

Не уточнил, само приложение лезет в БД и вытягивает записи по запросу.

Вот ссылка на аналог, по которому делал https://habrahabr.ru/post/111102/

Comment: А вы понимаете как работает сам паттерн MVC?

Comment: Да, как сам паттерн понимаю, делал во время обучения Java приложения с использованием MVC. Но вот когда в Spring столкнулся, мне боле-менее понятно, но вот есть вопросы. Техническим языком мне сложновато было понять, вот хотел бы чтобы объяснили человеческим :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Последовательность упрощенно такая:

1. Пришедший запрос обрабатывается сервлет Spring
2. Он определяет какой контроллер и метод в нем должен быть вызван
3. По параметрам метода и пр определяется какая модель нужна (в вашем случае это Map)
4. Создается модель
5. По возвращаемому значению определяется какое отображение (view) выбрать (в вашем случае это строка - имя отображения)
6. Вызывается метод и ему передаётся созданная модель
7. Метод что-то делает - меняет модель, меняет хранилище, посылает письма и т.п.
8. Метод возвращает результат
9. По результату определяется отображение
10. "Запускается" отображение и ему передается модель (из п. 4)
11. Результат посылают клиенту (браузеру)

Более детально процесс описан в документации [Web MVC framework](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html)

Comment: но так же есть и без параметров методы. Михаил, можете посоветовать книгу какую-нибудь для новичков про Spring?

Comment: есть. но перечислить все возможные варианты затруднительно, тем более  они хорошо описаны в документации.

Comment: вот описание всех вариантов возвращаемого значения https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-return-types

Comment: спасибо большое